# Rails check box resetting to default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a few check boxes in my view set to default as active:

```
<%= check_box "product[pr_attributes]", "ag_type", {:checked => @product.issenior?, :multiple => true, :checked => true}, checked_value = "ag:senior", unchecked_value = nil %>Senior(65-100)
```

The problem is, when I uncheck one of the defaults and save the changes, it defaults back to the checked state. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean to have two option keys for  `:checked`?

Mostly like the second one `:checked => true` is causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think the best way to do this in your case is use check_box_tag since your doing multiple answers for one attribute

syntax

> check_box_tag "id", "value", "boolean_if_checked"

so in your case:

> <%= check_box_tag "product[pr_attributes][]", "ag_type", @product.issenior?, {  } %>

Then just add the other attributes on the hash after the @product.issenior?

This way, you can create multiple checkboxes for pr_attributes, and then when you submit the form, pr_attributes will be an array of your choices.